# Exactly what index to strings in VB 2010 start from? 0 or 1?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

In VB 2010, if I do

```
dim str1 as string
dim str2 as string
dim str3 as string

str1 = "happy"
str2 = Mid(str1, 1, 2)
str3 = str1.substring(1,2)
Console.WriteLine(str2) ' The output for this is "ha"
Console.WriteLine(str3) ' The output for this is "ap"
```

So it appears that the `Mid()` function considers strings as starting from index 1, while the `Substring()` function looks at strings as if they start from 0. What is this inconsistency?

What's the real truth about strings in VB? Or is that VB strings actually start from 0, but different functions do as they please?

Comment: Isn't `Mid()` a hang-over from VB6, while `String.SubString()` is part of the CLR? If so, it would suggest that the behaviour you're observing is consistent with the design of the respective parts. If you use the `String.SubString()` method instead of `Mid()`, I think you'll get a consistent approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mid is an old Visual Basic function whereas Substring is a method in the String class. The Mid has to work like in the old Visual Basic, and String class naturally works the same in all .NET languages since it's part if the core.

Comment: So that means methods in the newer String class use zero-indexes? So I can assume that if I call the function as `mystring.function` then I use zero indexes, whereas if I do `function(myString)`, then I'll be using 1-indexes?

Comment: @user961627 If they are normal .NET functions they will have zero as a base. The other functions _probably_ are one-based, but better check the documentation. Old VB was by default one-based for arrays also, though there was an option to change that. It didn't affect the functions like Mid though

Comment: @user961627 - Instead of making assumptions, just read the documentation for the classes/methods you intend to use!

Answer (score 3):

Methods can each determine their own scheme.

According to [Strings.Mid Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sh1xas1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Starting position of the characters to return. ... Start is one-based.

And [String.Substring Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.